# Timestamp atualizar automáticamente com data atual

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Gostaria de saber se é possível, quando for feito um `INSERT` em uma determinada tabela, atualizar automaticamente o valor de uma outra coluna do tipo TIMESTAMP chamada **data** com a data e hora atual, similar a função `NOW()` do MySQL?

Comment: pode utilizar normalmente a função `NOW()` do MySQL na sua instrução do PHP. Se estiver utilizando `bind_param`, basta que não passe o parâmetro `$data` no INSERT, deixando o SGBD com essa responsabilidade.

Comment: Coloque o código que está tendo problemas.

Comment: Vocês não entenderam o problema do OP...

Comment: Colunas tipo `TIMESTAMP` (e não `DATETIME`) não fazem isso automaticamente?

Comment: @bfavaretto, depende da versão do MySQL e de como foi instalado o MySQL. Se for uma versão atual, e utilizada uma instalação *standard*, você está certo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

galera consegui com o simples comando sql abaixo. obrigado á todos

```
ALTER TABLE `grade_edt` CHANGE `data_ultima_mod` 
`data_ultima_mod` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: É uma alternativa pouco usual. O mais comum é deixar essas configurações de responsabilidade da aplicação, mas, funciona.

Comment: @FellipeSoares porque pouco usual? É tão relevante assim estar no domínio da aplicação a última alteração do registro?

Comment: @gmsantos, se porventura houverem alterações no hardware do banco de dados, alteração de versão do SGBD ou mesmo a troca do SGBD, poderá ser necessário remodelar a estrutura da tabela, quando que se a responsabilidade fosse da aplicação, você não teria essa preocupação. É mais uma questão de pensamento no ciclo de desenvolvimento. Talvez "usual" não seja a palavra correta a expressar.

Comment: Alteração de hardware ou versão do MySQL não irão influenciar na constraint da tabela. Única preocupação é se o sistema for sofrer uma troca de Sgdb ou precise rodar em vários bancos. Estou escrevendo uma resposta para explicar melhor isso. Mas se o sgbd nunca for mudar do mysql, acho o uso da constraint até melhor que gerenciar isso na aplicação

Comment: Entendo. Como a pergunta não foi a respeito de um cenário específico, uma resposta levando em conta uma possível troca de SGBD pode ser o mais ideal, visto que esta costuma ser uma dúvida frequente. Já tive problemas também com servidor de aplicação em UTC diferente do servidor de banco de dados, por exemplo.